# .htaccess em Plesk Linux ou Windows

Tags: php, htaccess

Meu arquivo .htaccess não funciona ,  vi esse link de ajuda mas como ajustar em meu .htaccess ?

*O site abre passa pelo index.php mas quando é redirecionado para o login dá `No input file specified`

[link aqui](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213385969-The-domain-shows-error-No-input-file-specified-)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /sma.loc/public_html/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Please comment this if you have uncommented the above
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /theme/errors/html/error_404.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Informe detalhadamente o que espera. Postar seu código e dizer que não funciona é muito amplo. Descreva em detalhes o que espera e cite exemplos, do contrário sua pergunta será marcada com baixa qualidade e ninguém conseguirá lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar os comentários e a documentação dos arquivos de configuração sem medo de errar (a não ser que seja algo muito crítico):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Em caso de erro 404, redireciona a requisição para seguinte página
    ErrorDocument 404 /theme/errors/html/error_404.php

    # Habilita mod_rewrite. Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
    RewriteEngine On

    # Condições de reescrita de rota
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update) 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Regra de reescrita de rota
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

[Documentação mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[Documentação sobre customização de respostas de erro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

Comment: Muito Obrigado !